# void pointer arithmetic error

Tags: c++, c, windows-ce, dfu

I am getting the unknown size error from the code below,

```
    atmel_device_info_t *info;

    int *ptr = row->offset + (void *) info
```

It is a casting problem,  what should I do to fix the error? thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you post the error? You haven't initialised `info`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot portably do arithmetic with a `void *` pointer. This makes sense, since it's a pointer to an unknown type of data, that data has no intrinsic size. The size of the pointed-to data is a central part of doing arithmetic.

usually a "byte" pointer works:

```
int *ptr = (int *) ((unsigned char *) info + row->offset);
```

The above assumes that `row->offset` is a byte offset, not an `int` offset. If you want the latter, cast accordingly:

```
int *ptr = (int *) info + row->offset;
```

Comment: Specifically if your `row->offset` value is in `byte`s then you need your pointers to be working in `byte` units.